# Ansible is being run in a world writable directory (/vagrant), ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source

Tags: ansible, vagrant, cygwin

trying to provision vagrant vm **(ubuntu/trusty64)** with **ansible_local** provisioner
from **cygwin**

[**WARNING**] Ansible is being run in a world writable directory **(/vagrant)**, ignoring it as an **ansible.cfg** source. For more information see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir

can anyone help me with this
please suggest how to configure the **ansible.cfg** file in cygwin
what should be the content of this and where should this be ?

Comment: already searched in google, couldn' t find a suitable configuration or explaination regarding this anible_local provisioner for windows cygwin .

Comment: i have tried using ansible provisioner which works perfectly from cygwin,  
but i want to try using ansibli_local provisioner which directly provision on guest vm,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did R & D and got help from the github vagrant community members.
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11707

previously before running **ansible_local** ,i had tried **ansible** provisioner.
so created new workspace folder and fired up vagrant up.

this time it worked from CYGWIN.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with **mount_options** in the `Vagrantfile`:

```
srv.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", disabled: false, mount_options: ["dmode=775"]
```